# Add description attribute to enum and read this description in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, enums

I’m wondering how to add description attributes to enum in TypeScript.
I would like to create enum as follows(or something similar):

```
public enum Sample
{
    [Display(Name = "Blah V")]
    V,

    [Display(Name = " Blah IV")]
    IV,

    [Display(Name = " Blah III")]
    III,
}
```

To be able to do basic operations on such enum I would create generic EnumHelper. This helper class should contain methods which allow: getting a description value, getting the name and numeric value. The question is how to achieve this in typescript? If it is not possible to add attributes to the enum, is there any way around?
I would like to be able to:

```
-  get number of enum value,
-  get description value,
-  get the name of enum field.
```

e.g. for Sample.IV it would be:

```
1, 
Blah IV, 
IV.
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Another interesting solution [found here](https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/map-your-typescript-enums-e402d406b229) is using ES6 Map:

```
export enum Sample {
  V,
  IV,
  III
}

export const SampleLabel = new Map<number, string>([
  [Sample.V, 'FIVE'],
  [Sample.IV, 'FOUR'],
  [Sample.III, 'THREE']
]);
```

USE

```
console.log(SampleLabel.get(Sample.IV)); // FOUR

SampleLabel.forEach((label, value) => {
  console.log(label, value);
});

// FIVE 0
// FOUR 1
// THREE 2
```

Answer (score 19):

Below method will be type safe (auto completion works) and it uses plain object. It is based on [this feature of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16687).

```
export enum Sample {
  I = 1,
  II = 2,
  III = 3
}

export const SampleLabel: { [key in Sample]: string } = {
  [Sample.I]: "ONE",
  [Sample.II]: "TWO",
  [Sample.III]: "THREE",
};
```

Comment: This is more elegant than the map solution IMO. Should also give you a compile error I think, if you miss a key from the SampleLabel?

Comment: @DanKing yes it does give you an error if you miss a key.

Answer (score 7):

A variation of the accepted answer. Replace `number` with your `enum` type to be more type safe.

```
 export enum Sample {
      V,
      IV,
      III
    }

export const SampleLabel = new Map<Sample, string>([
  [Sample.V, 'FIVE'],
  [Sample.IV, 'FOUR'],
  [Sample.III, 'THREE']
]);
```

Answer (score 6):

TypeScript doesn't allow you to add properties to an `enum` element, which at runtime is just a primitive string or number.  Instead you have to do something like create a new type which holds references to these elements and also has the methods or properties you want.

Here's one possible way to do it.  Start with your plain `enum` like this:

```
enum SampleEnum {
  V, IV, III
}
```

And let's give an interface definition for your extended type.  It has a `name`, a `description`, and a `number`.  Note that this type is generic so we can narrow down the `name` and `number` types shortly:

```
interface ISample<N extends number, S extends string> {
  readonly name: S;
  readonly description: string;
  readonly number: N;
}
```

Here is a function which can take your `SampleEnum` object and return something with the same keys but with values that implement the extended interface:

```
function makeSample<E extends Record<Extract<keyof E, string>, number>>(
  mapping: E
): { [K in Extract<keyof E, string>]: ISample<E[K], K> } {
  const ret = {} as { [K in Extract<keyof E, string>]: ISample<E[K], K> };
  (Object.keys(mapping).filter(k => k !== (+k) + "") as
    (Extract<keyof E, string>)[]
  ).forEach(k => {
    ret[k] = {
      name: k,
      description: "Blah " + k,
      number: mapping[k]
    }
  });
  return ret;
}
```

That might be a lot of type juggling, but it's basically just extracting the string-valued keys from `SampleEnum` (and ignoring the [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime) that adds numeric keys to numeric enums at runtime) and building an instance of the extended interface for each one, in a somewhat type-safe way.

Finally, let's create the `Sample` value and type which stands in for our `enum`:

```
const Sample = makeSample(SampleEnum);
type Sample = (typeof Sample)[keyof typeof Sample]
```

Okay, let's use it:

```
const nameOfIV = Sample.IV.name; // "IV"
console.log(nameOfIV); // "IV"
const numberOfIII = Sample.III.number; // SampleEnum.III
console.log(numberOfIII); // 1
const descriptionOfV = Sample.V.description; // string
console.log(descriptionOfV); // "Blah V"

const goodSample: Sample = Sample.III; // okay
const badSample: Sample = {
  name: "II", 
  description: "oops", 
  number: 3
}; // error, name doesn't match
```

Looks reasonable to me.  [See for yourself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20SampleEnum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20V%2C%20IV%2C%20III%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ISample%3CN%20extends%20number%2C%20S%20extends%20string%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20name%3A%20S%3B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20description%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20number%3A%20N%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20makeSample%3CE%20extends%20Record%3CExtract%3Ckeyof%20E%2C%20string%3E%2C%20number%3E%3E%28%0D%0A%20%20mapping%3A%20E%0D%0A%29%3A%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20Extract%3Ckeyof%20E%2C%20string%3E%5D%3A%20ISample%3CE%5BK%5D%2C%20K%3E%20%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20ret%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20Extract%3Ckeyof%20E%2C%20string%3E%5D%3A%20ISample%3CE%5BK%5D%2C%20K%3E%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%28Object.keys%28mapping%29.filter%28k%20%3D%3E%20k%20%21%3D%3D%20%28%2Bk%29%20%2B%20%22%22%29%20as%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28Extract%3Ckeyof%20E%2C%20string%3E%29%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%29.forEach%28k%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ret%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20k%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20description%3A%20%22Blah%20%22%20%2B%20k%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20number%3A%20mapping%5Bk%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20ret%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20Sample%20%3D%20makeSample%28SampleEnum%29%3B%0D%0Atype%20Sample%20%3D%20%28typeof%20Sample%29%5Bkeyof%20typeof%20Sample%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20nameOfIV%20%3D%20Sample.IV.name%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22IV%22%0D%0Aconsole.log%28nameOfIV%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22IV%22%0D%0Aconst%20numberOfIII%20%3D%20Sample.III.number%3B%20%2F%2F%20SampleEnum.III%0D%0Aconsole.log%28numberOfIII%29%3B%20%2F%2F%201%0D%0Aconst%20descriptionOfV%20%3D%20Sample.V.description%3B%20%2F%2F%20string%0D%0Aconsole.log%28descriptionOfV%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22Blah%20V%22%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20goodSample%3A%20Sample%20%3D%20Sample.III%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%0D%0Aconst%20badSample%3A%20Sample%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20%22II%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20description%3A%20%22oops%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20number%3A%203%0D%0A%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%2C%20name%20doesn%27t%20match). Of course there are other ways to approach it but this should hopefully give you an idea.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: The main reason I've asked that question was to get know how to transfer C# enum with descriptions to angular selector where the value is enum's value and the name is enum's description. Probably in such case, it is better and easier to convert c# enum to typescript class. Thank you for the very descriptive answer!

Answer (score 4):

this pattern worked for me:

```
export enum PriceTypes {
    Undefined = 0,
    UndefinedDescription = 'Undefined' as any,
    UserEntered = 1,
    UserEnteredDescription = 'User Entered' as any,
    GeneratedFromTrade = 2,
    GeneratedFromTradeDescription = 'Generated From Trade' as any,
    GeneratedFromFreeze = 3,
    GeneratedFromFreezeDescription = 'Generated Rom Freeze' as any
}
```

...

```
    GetDescription(e: any, id: number): string {
        return e[e[id].toString() + "Description"];
    }
    getPriceTypeDescription(price: IPricePoint): string {
        return this.GetDescription(PriceTypes, price.priceType);
    }
```

Comment: Bad use of enums. UndefinedDescription is not a valid PriceType.